# Export environment variables from child bash script in GNU Make

Tags: bash, makefile, environment-variables, export, gnu-make

I have a script "set_env.py" that outputs the following uppon execution:

```
export MY_VAR_1=some_value
export MY_VAR_2=some_other_value
```

I cannot change this script, it is supplied in my current environment.

Further I have a Makefile that looks like this:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

all: set_env
    env | grep MY_VAR    

set_env:
    eval ./set_env.py
```

With this makefile I expected the grep to list my two variables, however it seems the environment is not set.

I suspect this is because make creates a sub-environment for each line and so the variables set on the first line will not be available in the second.

So the question is, **how would I go about exporting the environment from the untouchable script in my makefile**?

Comment: Try this: eval $(./set_env.py)

Comment: @Šerg: Boy have I tried that and like 100 variations: ``, $(), $$() etc. With quotes, wihtout quotes, absolute path, you name it.

Comment: I think it is limitation in make that environment of one line is not carried to the next. The only way to export is to use the export keyword in the makefile itself.

Comment: Just do `include set_env_py`

Comment: @Matt: set_env.py is a python script. I could direct output to a file and then include that. Can I do that from a target? I would expect include to be global

Comment: Only if it's done within the same recipe, and `.ONESHELL:` is in effect.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with make per se.  Make always invokes a shell to run your recipe: make itself doesn't try to parse and run shell syntax.  It doesn't matter if you use `.ONESHELL`, or any other combination of shell methods in your recipe: it's an ironclad unalterable fact of POSIX systems that a child process can *NEVER* modify its parent's environment.  Once a child exits, its environment is gone.  It doesn't matter whether the processes are involved are `make`, `/bin/sh`, or anything else.  No environment changes in a recipe can impact the environment of `make`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the output of the python is valid *make*.
One option then is to read the output of the python directly into the makefile.
The only fly in the ointment is that `$(shell)` doesn't cut the mustard.

```
include Environment.mk

PHONY: test
test:
    env | grep MY_VAR

Environment.mk:
    ./set_env.py >$@-tmp
    mv $@-tmp $@
```

How does this work?
The first thing that *make* tries to do is to ensure the makefile itself is up-to-date.
Since we have told it to include `Environment.mk`,
*make* must ensure that is up-to-date too.

- *Make* finds a rule for `Environment.mk`
- The python is run, creating `Environment.mk`
- `Environment.mk` is read in, creating two *make* variables with the export attribute
- The makefile is now up-to-date, so *make* proceeds on to the target (`test` in this case)
- *Make* runs `test`'s recipe, exporting any variables with the export attribute.

No recursion, but you should ensure the python always spits out *make* compatible syntax.

### EDIT

As @raspy points out, this is not the whole story.
As it stands,
once `Environment.mk` has been created,
it will never be regenerated.

If `set_env.py` ever generates different output,
you should tell *make* what conditions these are by adding dependencies.

If `set_env.py` takes a trivial time to run,
I advise a simple `.PHONY`.
That way it will run every time you run *make*,
and `Environment.mk` will never be stale.

```
.PHONY: Environment.mk
```

Comment: I would write `Environment.mk: set_env.py` to force regeneration when `set_env.py` changes. It would also be good to keep that Python script deterministic, so that it does not change its output, otherwise `Environment.mk` should be `.PHONY`.

Comment: @raspy Agreed, as well as all the other dependencies that the python requires. `.PHONY: Environment.mk` might be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive make is your friend I'm afraid.

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    eval $$(./set_env.py) && ${MAKE} test

.PHONY: test
test:
    env | grep MY_VAR
```

There are a few moving parts here.

- `make all` executes the shell command `eval $(./set_env.py) && make test`
- The shell first does the command substitution

  - `$(./set_env.py)` is replaced by the export commands
- The export commands are passed to the (shell) `eval` command

  - The environment variables are defined, *but only for this shell invocation*
- The `eval` succeeds, so the execution passes to the command after the `&&`
- *Make* runs recursively, but this second *make* has an augmented environment